# Best practices for commoning an RPi3B 0V plane with a MB102 (or equivalent) 3.3v/5.0v power adapter

Tags: pi-3

I would like to common the GND from a RPi3B with
the 0v planes from a 3.3v/5.0v power adapter.

Can they be connected together? I do not want to
fry my RPi3B.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can be connected together.  Indeed they need to be connected together if you want to connect a Pi GPIO to a device powered by the MB102 - the device and Pi must share a common voltage reference.

Comment: Thanks. However the power adapter (Elegoo) [+] and [-] power rails

Comment: @JohnRose The "-" power rail is ground.  As in a battery "-" is connected to ground.